# Tool tip for review list on a user's network profile is wrong

Tags: bug, network-profile, tooltips

On a users network profile there is a section where you can see a list of reviews a user has done on all Stack Exchange sites located at User's Network Profile > Activity > Reviews.

Hovering your cursor over the review filter will pop up a tool tip with the following text:

> "show approved or rejected reviews on suggested edits"

[image]

This is of course not the case as this page shows all the different review types a user has done.